# How to do several division and store the remainders in new variables in R?

Tags: r, aggregate, division

I have a data frame, each of the data point has a structure like: ID, measure, timemark

```
ID    measure   timemark   
001   12         15    
003   3          13            
004   365        0                   
003   1          13
```

ID is a unique study ID for a person, while measure is the number of days the person using a service at that time, and timemark is a number range from 0 to 51 which indicate the 52 weeks in a year x

Now I want to create dataframe of 52 columns, each of them consists of the number of days they spent in the service that week (so maximal number of days should be 7 each week). For each person, they can have more than one entry in a time point. In this sense, the total days should be the sum of the two rows.

So I want to make it like:

```
ID    ... week13 week14 week15 week 16   
001   ... 0      0      7      5        
003   ... 4      0      0      0            
004   ... 7      7      7      7
```

I was struggling with the logic inside and guess it would be related to the quotient and remainder of measure, but I couldn't make the way through. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not following your logic. What have you tried so far, since that might help make it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can first create one row per `ID` and `timemark` and `sum` the `measure` values. We create a list dividing `measure` into steps of 7 along with it's remainder. Using `unnest_longer` we get the data in long format and create `timemark` column appending the week number and finally `spread` the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, timemark) %>%
  summarise(measure = sum(measure)) %>%
  mutate(measure = list(c(rep(7, floor(measure/7)), measure %% 7))) %>%
  unnest_longer(measure) %>%
  mutate(timemark = paste0('week', first(timemark) + 0:(n() - 1))) %>%
  slice(1:pmin(n(), 52)) %>%
  mutate(timemark = factor(timemark, levels = paste0('week', 0:51))) %>%
  spread(timemark, measure)
  #Or using pivot_wider in new tidyr
  #pivot_wider(names_from = timemark, values_from = measure)


# A tibble: 3 x 53
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID week0 week1 week2 week3 week4 week5 week6 week7 week8 week9 week10 week11 week12 week13 week14 week15 week16
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      7      5
#2     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA      4     NA     NA     NA
#3     4     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7      7      7      7      7      7      7      7
# … with 35 more variables: week17 <dbl>, week18 <dbl>, week19 <dbl>, week20 <dbl>, week21 <dbl>, week22 <dbl>,
#   week23 <dbl>, week24 <dbl>, week25 <dbl>, week26 <dbl>, week27 <dbl>, week28 <dbl>, week29 <dbl>, week30 <dbl>,
#   week31 <dbl>, week32 <dbl>, week33 <dbl>, week34 <dbl>, week35 <dbl>, week36 <dbl>, week37 <dbl>, week38 <dbl>,
#   week39 <dbl>, week40 <dbl>, week41 <dbl>, week42 <dbl>, week43 <dbl>, week44 <dbl>, week45 <dbl>, week46 <dbl>,
#   week47 <dbl>, week48 <dbl>, week49 <dbl>, week50 <dbl>, week51 <dbl>
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 3L), measure = c(12L, 3L, 365L, 
1L), timemark = c(15L, 13L, 0L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! However, dont know why there is no function unnest_longer() in my tidyr package.....

Comment: @cryingintheparty Use `unnest` instead of `unnest_longer`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to leave what I tried for you. First, I created a master data frame that contains all combination of `ID` and `timemark` for each `ID` using `expand()`. Then, I created `result` in the following way. I defined groups by `ID` and `timemark` and summed up measure. Then, I identified how many weeks (rows) I needed in order to expand the result in the first `mutate()`. Then, I expanded the data frame using expandRows() in the `splitstackshape` package. Then, I updated the numbers in `timemark` to have correct week numbers in the 2nd `mutate()`. Then, I handled some calculation to assign the number of days in each week. `lag(measure - 7 * row_number(), default = 7)` creates a vector that contains how many days are still left in `measure`. I needed to replace some of the numbers using logical conditions. For each `group`, when the number of row is 1, assign the value in `measure`. When `res` is larger than 7, assign 7 to `res`. (Any number larger than 7 is 7 since each week (row) can take up to 7 days.) Otherwise, keep the original value in `res`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(splitstackshape)

master <- expand(mydf, timemark = 0:51, ID)

group_by(mydf, ID, timemark) %>% 
summarize(measure = sum(measure)) %>% 
ungroup %>% 
group_by(group = 1:n()) %>% 
mutate(nrow = as.integer(measure / 7) + 1) %>% 
expandRows(count = "nrow") %>%
mutate(timemark = first(timemark):(first(timemark) + n() - 1),
       res = lag(measure - 7 * row_number(), default = 7),
       res = case_when(n() == 1 ~ as.numeric(measure),
                       res > 7 ~ 7,
                       TRUE ~ res)) -> result
```

The final step was to join `result` to `master`. I dropped unnecessary columns, made the data frame wide, and updated column names.

```
left_join(master, result, by = c("ID", "timemark"))%>% 
select(-c(measure, group)) %>% 
spread(key = timemark, value = res, fill = 0) %>%
rename_at(vars(-ID),
          .funs = list(~paste("week", ., sep = "")))


     ID week0 week1 week2 week3 week4 week5 week6 week7 week8 week9 week10 week11 week12 week13 week14 week15 week16
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0      0      0      7      5
2     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0      0      0      4      0      0      0
3     4     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7      7      7      7      7      7      7      7
# … with 35 more variables: week17 <dbl>, week18 <dbl>, week19 <dbl>, week20 <dbl>, week21 <dbl>, week22 <dbl>,
#   week23 <dbl>, week24 <dbl>, week25 <dbl>, week26 <dbl>, week27 <dbl>, week28 <dbl>, week29 <dbl>, week30 <dbl>,
#   week31 <dbl>, week32 <dbl>, week33 <dbl>, week34 <dbl>, week35 <dbl>, week36 <dbl>, week37 <dbl>, week38 <dbl>,
#   week39 <dbl>, week40 <dbl>, week41 <dbl>, week42 <dbl>, week43 <dbl>, week44 <dbl>, week45 <dbl>, week46 <dbl>,
#   week47 <dbl>, week48 <dbl>, week49 <dbl>, week50 <dbl>, week51 <dbl>
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 3L), measure = c(12L, 3L, 365L, 
1L), timemark = c(15L, 13L, 0L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: thank you very much of your help!
However, when i try, it gives this error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys. 

How could I combine the keys with both "ID" and "timemark"?

Comment: @cryingintheparty I do not have your data so I cannot really help you out. Can you modify your sample data?